# can its possible to make for loop for array of objects, removing duplicate and add the values which consists of same user

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a array of objects, inside every object user and value(value 
      consist of array). This has to minimize to remove duplicate users and 
      add data to array of values.

```
      ex---------

      [ { user: 'VAY9090', value: [ 'KL65' ] },
      { user: 'VAY9090', value: [ 'KL6I' ] },
      { user: 'VAY9092', value: [ 'KLMF' ] },
      { user: 'VAY9092', value: [ 'KLMQ' ] },
      { user: 'VAY9090', value: [ 'KLMR' ] },
      { user: 'BTD9891', value: [ 'KLMS' ] },
      { user: 'VAY9090', value: [ 'KLVZ' ] },
      { user: 'VAY9033', value: [ 'KMYJ' ] },
      { user: 'BTD9891', value: [ 'KMYK' ] } ]

      convert to 

      [

     { user: 'VAY9090', value: [ 'KL65','KL6I','KLMR','KLVZ' ] },
     { user: 'VAY9092', value: [ 'KLMQ','KLMQ' ]},
     { user: 'BTD9891', value: [ 'KLMS','KMYK'] },
     { user: 'VAY9033', value: [ 'KMYJ' ] }
     ]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because i cant see any research effort, not even a try to solve this.

Comment: @raghunandan have you tried searching on Google and Stack Overflow for the answer to your question? If so, please tell us what you have found and why it didn't help you solve your problem.

Comment: many for loop helped me from stack over flow, but my scenario is different so could solve that problem, so took help from posting the data..!! and new to this kind of for loop and all..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
var data = [
  { user: 'VAY9090', value: [ 'KL65' ] },
  { user: 'VAY9090', value: [ 'KL6I' ] },
  { user: 'VAY9092', value: [ 'KLMF' ] },
  { user: 'VAY9092', value: [ 'KLMQ' ] },
  { user: 'VAY9090', value: [ 'KLMR' ] },
  { user: 'BTD9891', value: [ 'KLMS' ] },
  { user: 'VAY9090', value: [ 'KLVZ' ] },
  { user: 'VAY9033', value: [ 'KMYJ' ] },
  { user: 'BTD9891', value: [ 'KMYK' ] }
];

var convertedData = convert(data);

console.log(convertedData);

function convert(data) {
  var result = [];
  var obj = {};

  data.forEach(function(item) {
    obj[item.user] = obj[item.user] || {
      user: item.user,
      value: []
    };

    obj[item.user].value = obj[item.user].value.concat(item.value);
  });

  for(var i in obj) {
    result.push(obj[i]);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy..!! Its working fine